# Way of passing pointer (strings) deep down to functions

Tags: c, pointers

I'm having some dillema. I want to edit, in this example, strings in functions. My problem is that using *****ptr when going down feels weird. Is there any way of doing this 'more' proper way?

Pseudo-code:

```
// all funX return array length
int fun1(int **ptr){
    //some READ/WRITE on pointers, like mallocs, giving value etc.
    int len = 0;
    len = fun2(&ptr);
    return len;
}

int fun2(int ***ptr){
 // some more READ/WRITE on pointers, like mallocs, giving value etc.
 // what about going even deeper?
}

int main(){
    int *someString = NULL;
    int len = 0;
    len = fun1(&someString);
    // some string operations
    free(someString);
return 1;
}
```

Best regards,
voodoo16.

Comment: You only need one layer of indirection, no matter how many times you're passing the address of the original pointer around.

Comment: There are no strings in your code!

Comment: Please read more about what is a pointer. It is only an address. When someone gives your address to another people, he does not give the address of your address (?) but the same address that you gived to him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to add a new level of indirection each time, you simply pass your pointer to the next function.

You want this:

```
int fun2(int **ptr) {
  // some more READ/WRITE on pointers, like mallocs, giving value etc.
  // what about going even deeper?

  *ptr = (int*)malloc(190);   // 190 is just some arbitrary length for test purposes
  return 190;
}


// all funX return array length
int fun1(int **ptr) {
  //some READ/WRITE on pointers, like mallocs, giving value etc.
  int len = 0;               // BTW you dont need to initialize to 0
  len = fun2(ptr);
  return len;
}


int main() {
  int *someString = NULL;
  int len = 0;               // BTW you dont need to initialize to 0
  len = fun1(&someString);
  // some string operations
  free(someString);
  return 1;
}
```